# [__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: iphone

```
-(id)init{
    if (self==[super init]) {            
        NSMutableArray *listname = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"cu",@"al",@"zn",@"au",@"ru",@"fu",@"rb",@"pb",@"wr", nil];            
        NSMutableArray *listVolumn = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[listname count]];           
        for (int i=0; i<[listname count]; i++) {
            [listVolumn addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:0]];
        }
        nsmutabledictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:listVolumn forKeys:listname];
    }
    return self;
}
```

in my init method,I defined two NSMutableArray,and added to NSMutableDictionary nsmutabledictionary.
in my other method:

```
[nsmutabledictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:100] forKey:@"cu"];
```

but it crash at above line:
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
nsmutabledictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:listVolumn forKeys:listname];
```

should be

```
nsmutabledictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:listVolumn forKeys:listname];
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code I see that `nsmutabledictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:listVolumn forKeys:listname];`
 that line you declared it to be NSDictionary while you intented it to be NSMutableDictionary