# how to check empty array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have one array. In that array I want check if array is empty then remove it. I am trying to check that array is nil or count 0 but not working.

Here is my array :

```
data(
(
abc,
xyz
),
(
yui,
hsjd
),
(
),
)
```

In data array last array is empty and I want to remove from data array. Please suggest me any idea.

Comment: do you have an array whose individual elements are also an array? and are you using objective-c or swift?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889285/how-to-check-value-null-and-replace-it-in-nsdictionary try this way is solved your issues.

Comment: I am using objective-c.

Comment: from where you get ? it seem it is not represented as array inside array

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** *Instead of Downvoting because a question has already been downvoted so It's a fair game, try reading the answer first which contains both stable and potentially unstable ways.*

Your data array is basically an array of arrays. Make your data array a `NSMutableArray` like this:

```
data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: data];
```

Now remove the empty enclosed arrays like this:

**(Stable Way)**

```
NSMutableIndexSet *itemsToDiscard = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
NSArray *item;
NSUInteger index = 0;

for (item in data) {
    if ([item count]<=0)
        [itemsToDiscard addIndex:index];
    index++;
}

[data removeObjectsAtIndexes:discardedItems];
```

Or by this approach which is not recommended at all but I am just putting it out there because it is working for me. I suggest however you use the first approach.

(**Potentially unstable way**)

```
for(id arr in data) {
    if ([arr isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
       if(arr.count<=0)
       { 
          [data removeObject:arr];
       }
    }
}
```

This will remove the empty arrays enclosed in data.

Comment: Why create the `arr` array? Plus, this code will fail if there are two empty arrays in a row. You need to iterate in reverse.

Comment: My bad @rmaddy thanks for pointing it out. How about using for each loop?

Comment: Also as much as I'd accept the downvotes, It would be more helpful to leave a comment for your reason to do so so that I might improve the answer. Like rmaddy did and I improved the answer.

Comment: You can't modify an array being iterated with a `for in` loop.

Comment: @rmaddy I just did that. You can modify that.

Comment: No, calling `removeObject:` on the mutable array while using the `for in` will result in a crash.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure? it is NOT crashing for me and it is removing the undesired objects form the mutableArray. I have just run it.

Comment: Crashes for me. Are you sure that in your test you are actually removing an object from the mutable array during the loop?

Comment: @rmaddy Doesn't crash for me. You can see it here. http://imgur.com/a/lzsvb. Or should I make a video of it?

Comment: That's really strange. That code crashes for me. And this site is full of examples of such code crashing. I don't know why it is working for you. The docs even say it isn't safe to modify a mutable array while iterating this way.

Comment: @rmaddy it might be so. Anyhow I have edited the answer, would you take a look at it now?

Comment: Smh on piggyback downvote. The answer has been edited with a correct and stable solution. Why one earth would you downvote that? @rmaddy's downvotes were absolutely correct for concrete reasons I have no idea why the second bloke downvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are iterating through an array that is changing throughout the iteration, you'll have to use a while-loop with the condition as an index being smaller than the size of the array, like so:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayContents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @[@"abc", @"def"],@[@1,@2,@3], @[], nil];
NSLog( @"Pre while-loop: \n%@", arrayContents);
NSUInteger index = 0;
while (index < [arrayContents count]) {
    BOOL didRemove = false;
    if ([[arrayContents objectAtIndex: index] count] == 0) {
        [arrayContents removeObjectAtIndex: index];
        didRemove = true;

    }
    if (didRemove == false)
        index += 1;

}
NSLog( @"Post while-loop: \n%@", arrayContents);
```

If nothing was removed, you would increment `index`, but if something was removed, you don't increment the `index`. Instead you loop again at the same `index`, because if you increase the index after removing, you'll "skip" an iteration.

Hope this works for your situation :)

Answer (score -1):

The simple way is to just loop through each subarray in the array, and check if it is empty. Since you cannot delete entries while looping, you can just keep a counter and remove them after.

In Swift 2.0

```
var arrays = [["abc","def"],["ghi","jkl"],[], ["mno"], [], ["pqr"], [], ["stv"]]
var numberToRemove = 0
for idx in 0..<arrays.count {
if arrays[idx].isEmpty {
    numberToRemove++
    arrays.insert(arrays.removeAtIndex(idx), atIndex: 0)
}
}

arrays.removeRange(0..<numberToRemove)
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C. Answers should be in the proper language.